# How can I reliably "hold" a package in Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I have a package in Debian that has been manually patched (not ideal, I know) that I must hold at its current version so upgrades don't overwrite the patched changes (I will manually inspect and apply security updates). As I understand it, there are a few ways to approach this:

- apt-pinning (see `apt_preferences(5)`)
- `aptitude hold`
- `dpkg --set-selections`
- setting it with `dselect`?

I've read that one hold won't affect another (so, for example, using `aptitude hold` won't prevent `apt-get` or `dselect` from upgrading the package). What needs to be done to 100% ensure that Debian's tools will never upgrade the package unless I remove the hold?

Comment: Just a comment, 9 years ago someone created a bug in Debian's bug system about how really can *hold* a package, and seems like there is (or was) some issues using aptitude hold ( LINK: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=146207 )

Comment: That someone would be me. :-). Still an open bug, though the people who have recently revived aptitude said they would take a look at it.

Comment: Daniel Hartwig wrote to me: "Been aware of this issue with holds since I began working on aptitude. At the moment I have not given it a thorough look as my focus has been on getting multi-arch working. It's age and significance does intimidate me a bit. There is also the matter that aptitude somewhat "interprets" dpkg states on startup to determine what, if any, changes and how they should incorporate in to it's internal state model. Be assured that this one will not be left alone -- I am always mindful of it when looking at related areas of the code."

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/146207 is supposedly fixed in the version of aptitude uploaded to unstable.

Answer (score 8):

`aptitude` and `dpkg` have separate *hold* functions which won't respect each other, unfortunately. So you have to set both if you use both tools:

apt/dpkg:
`echo $PACKETNAME hold | dpkg --set-selections`

aptitude:
`aptitude hold $PACKETNAME`

Comment: It appears that there is now `apt-mark hold` which according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages, does the same thing as `dpkg --set-selections`.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach in this particular case (patched package) could be to install the patched version in `/usr/local`. Debian won't touch that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `aptitude hold <package>` will be honored by the others unless you explicitly order it upgraded (such as hitting + while the cursor is on the "upgradeable packages" field in aptitude).

Comment: Looks like this isn't true, see the comments above.