# TexLive 2018, after installation Debian "updates" some files and breaks it

Tags: debian, latex, crunchbang

After I install the newest version of TexLive through the official installer ([this one](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)), if I run a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` apt-get finds a series of packages to update, related, I think, to the package `tex-common`. Such packages, though, aren't updated and refer to an older distribution of TeXlive from 2016.

Of course this creates issues, because if I run `pdflatex -v` after such update I find out that pdflatex is trying to use the 2016 of TeXlive, not the 2018 one, and any document's exportation won't work.

On Ubuntu I'd solve the issue with a PPA, but PPAs aren't made for Debian and in fact the TexLive's one won't work properly here.

Is there a way to permanently tell Debian to not update those packages with the ones he find in the repositories?

**EDIT:**

The situation turned out to be different from what I explained, so my question here is totally wrong, and thus it must be ignored/deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always mark/hold a specific Debian package, for it not to be updated.

As in:

```
echo "tex-common hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-mark hold tex-common
```

Just be sure you understand the security implications of not having packages updated, and that it can (slightly) complicate your life, when it comes the time to upgrade for a new Debian version.

In that way, when you are doing security updates, new versions of those packages won't be offered by default.

see related question [How can I reliably "hold" a package in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/how-can-i-reliably-hold-a-package-in-debian)

Have also a look at [Debian Reference - Chapter 2. Debian package management](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html)